# Trigger ComboBox selection event for the same item

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` that has the following implementation as shown in code below. The problem I am facing is that I can only trigger `ChangeListener` one time for a selected item. I would like to trigger as many times as I click on the same item.

```
int lastGridRowPos = 4;
ObservableList<String> options = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                "IdentityFile",
                "LocalForward",
                "RemoteForward",
                "ForwardAgent",
                "ForwardX11"
        );

ComboBox propertyBox = new ComboBox(options);
propertyBox.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue ov, String t, String t1) {
        System.out.println("SELECTED=" + t1);
        int rowCounter = getRowCount(grid);
        grid.add(new Label(t1), 0, rowCounter + 1);
        TextField field = newTextFieldWithIdPrompt(t1.toUpperCase(), "");
        grid.add(field, 1, rowCounter + 1);
        propertyBox.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
    }
});
```

I was trying to clear the selection so that I can click on the same item again (hoping that the combo box sees a change in item) by using `propertyBox.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();` but its not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am almost sure that a simpler solution exists, but you could try to use the `setCellFactory` and add an `EventFilter` to the returned `ListCell` instance:

```
propertyBox.setCellFactory(param -> {
    final ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (!empty)
                setText(item);
        }
    };
    cell.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e -> {
        propertyBox.setValue(null);
        propertyBox.getSelectionModel().select(cell.getItem());

        e.consume();
    });
    return cell;
});
```

These `ListCell`s will capture mouse pressed events on the list items inside the `ComboBox` and consumes these event. Then they manually set the `valueProperty` of the `ComboBox` to null (to erase the selection) then it sets this property to the item what the `ListCell` is displaying.

Then in the `ChangeListener` of the `valueProperty` you just need to check for `null`s:

```
propertyBox.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
    if (newVal != null)
        System.out.println("Selected: " + newVal);
});
```

**Additional note:**

I don't know your exact use case but maybe a `Menu` with `MenuItem`s is a better solution .

Comment: Thanks for the solution (I still have to try it out in my case). Now when you have said it, I wonder why a menu wouldn't work for me instead. I will take a look at the menu. All I want to do is provide a list of things for the user to choose from where he is allowed to choose the same item over and over again.